# How to assign homepage layout to a profile in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Any idea on how to assign a homepage layout to a profile via Eclipse? I tried to checkout all the metadata components in my project but can't look for homepage layout assignments under the "layoutAssignments>".

Comment: I agree with you that this is needed.  It appears that it cannot be done via the metadata.  It appears salesforce metadata is not complete.  There are still manual tasks that must be done via the UI.   Very sad!  It appears salesforce has moved on to "communities" and left the many confusingly named "portals" behind.  :(  what a mess!

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps --

Setup ->Home Page Layout ->Click **Page Layout Assignment** button->Click **Edit Assignment** button->Select the required page layout to set in front of respective profile.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I would like to do that using Eclipse and not in directly from the org.